# Question Related to Vram In Windows server 2019

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, server, vram

I have had created VM instances using google cloud platform (using console). The VM is a based on WINDOWS SERVER 2019! I have been successful in making one but unable to get some virtual ram in the instances. It (VRAM) shows zero. Does adding GPU not increase the vram? If not then what increases them? I am looking to increase the same for gaming purposes and using software like ADOBE AND AUTODESK too...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Instances created with additional GPU's (Like Tesla K80 and other) have all specified amount of GPU memory (VRAM).**

You can find list of all GPU's in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus#gpus-list).
Every GPU has an amount of memory specified in the table.

**If you create a VM with one K80 GPU it will kave 16GB of DDR6 memory available** (nothing to do with the type of the machine or actual RAM assigned).

You can find how much of VRAM a GPU has in the Device manager; find "Display adapters" and expand it and find your card; it's all in the "general" tab.

And regarding any Adobe or Autodesk software I can't really tell if having Tesla will be of advantage..